# How to fetch latest record of each user in a table using Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have n users in a table and for each user, I'm saving their log-in and log-out time in a separate table. I want to get the details of the users who haven't logged-in for 2 days using Laravel eloquent.

Users table structure

```
id | name | email
```

Log table structure

```
id |action | user_id | created_at | updated_at
```

So far I have done this much:

```
$users = LogsData::where('action','Login')->where('created_at','<',Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->get();
```

But the output has users who have logged-in within 2 days also.

EDIT:
I got the query, I need to convert this into eloquent.

I solved it myself. Here is the solution:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM actions t1
  JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(id) as maxid  FROM actions where action = "LOGIN" GROUP BY user_id) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.id = t2.maxid
     where created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Comment: just `group by` user_id

Comment: @Saengdaet Can I use group by in a non-key column?

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: Is Logs a relation setup in the user model?

Comment: No, it's not. I haven't setup any relations

Comment: are there any objections to using eloquent relations?

Comment: Is the database server time the same as the PHP server time? If you're using MySQL you can check by executing `select now();` and using tinker execute `date("h:i:s");`

Comment: I’m testing locally

Comment: The time `Carbon::now()` gives should be according to the `timezone` configuration in `config/app.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to get the last data of each user, you can sort the `id` desc and then group by `user_id` to get the latest data

```
$users = LogsData::where('action','Login')
                 ->whereDate('created_at','<',Carbon::today()->subDays(1))
                 ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get();
```

to use `groupBy`, you have to change the `strict` from your config value into `false`. But if you don't want to change your config file, this query can help you. You just need to translate it into laravel query version

```
SELECT * FROM log_datas AS ld WHERE ld.action = 'Login' AND ld.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM log_datas WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP_BY user_id)
```

Comment: Yes. It is throwing exception.

Comment: Contains non-aggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause...

Comment: go to your `config/database.php` then change `strict => false`

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe u can try the raw query in your database to make sure the result

Comment: @Saengdaet This actually worked for me - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a join to the logs table first, and because MySQL always seeks the path of least resistance, you need to join it the other way around: there may not exists log entries YOUNGER than 1 day.

```
$users = DB::from('users')
    ->leftJoin('logs', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'logs.user_id')
            ->where('logs.action', '=', 'Login')
            ->where('logs.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(2));
    })
    ->whereNull('logs.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using eloquent relations

Take note of your namespaces make sure that App\LogsData for example is correct here

```php
// in your User Model
public function logsData()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LogsData');
}

// in your LogsData Model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function scopeLoginActions($query)
{
    return $query->where('action', 'Login');
}
```

Then you can access data with

```php
User::whereHas('logsData', function ($query) {
    $query->loginActions()->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2));
})->get();

// and if you require the login records
User::with('logsData')->whereHas('logsData', function ($query) {
    $query->loginActions()->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2));
})->get();

// and if you require an individual login record
User::with(['logsData' => function($query) {
    $query->loginActions()->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2))->first();
})->whereHas('logsData', function ($query) {
    $query->loginActions()->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2));
})->get();
```