# Laravel join and get the latest series of records from second table for every instance of a unique row in first table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am joining two tables (products and records; records represent inventory records of this product for a particular store), and trying to select the latest row from the second table (the most recent inventory record for a particular product) based on a column in the first (the product's id, referenced in records as product_id); I'm trying to do this with Laravel 5.1.

```
    $query = Product::status(1);
    $query->join('records', function ($join) use ($order) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'records.product_id')
             ->where('records.location_id', '=', $order->location->id)
             ->where('records.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(1));

    });
```

This will get the records in the last day, but I want to get the most recent record with this product_id. Bear in mind that I'm tracking several days worth of inventory. ->latest() does not work for me.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009611/how-to-fetch-latest-record-of-each-user-in-a-table-using-laravel-eloquent) is similar to yours an the answer will help you.